# Persisting the app start time in Dropwizard and mysql

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I am trying to save the time dropwizard server is restarted in the database. For this I created  the following

The App object

```
JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "app")

@NamedQuery(name = "App.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM App d")

public class App implements  Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    AppDAO adao;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id;

    @JsonProperty
    Date started;

    public App ( Date started) {
        this.started = started;
    }
```

The AppDAO class

```
public class AppDAO extends  AbstractDAO<Appr>  {
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public AppDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }

    public Session session;

    public App create(App app) {
        return persist(app);
    }
```

The main() method class

```
public class Main Application extends Application<MainConfiguration> {

    private final HibernateBundle<DeployerConfiguration> hibernate = new HibernateBundle<AppConfiguration>(App.class) {
        public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(
                AppConfiguration configuration) {
            return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<AppConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        bootstrap.addBundle(hibernate);
    }

    public static void main() {
        final AppDAO ddao = new AppDAO(hibernate.getSessionFactory());
        App app = new App(new Date());
        adao.create(app);
    }
```

I get the following error

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: No session currently bound to execution context
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Please update if you've found a solution!

Comment: I ended up using raw jdbc in the data access object's create method.

Comment: Did you get it working without the raw jdbc?

Comment: I did not. Along the way I did learn that adding @UnitOfWork alleviated "No session currently bound" Exceptions, but that was for Resource methods, which will not help in this context.